# AngularJS + dotdotdot plugin don't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have small problem with using a dotdotdot JQuery plugin with AngularJS. There is my HTML code:

```
<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" ng-repeat="video in videos track by $index">
  <a href="{{thumbsPath + video.thumbnail}}" class="thumb">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img ng-src="{{thumbsPath + video.thumbnail}}" alt="">
        <div class="caption">
            <p class="video-title" dotdotdot>{{video.name}}</p>
       </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

And this is my dotdotdot directive:

```
videoControllers.directive('dotdotdot', function() {
 return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        $(element).dotdotdot({'watch':true});
    };
});
```

I want to make my {{video.name}} shorter, but when I add dotdotdot - it doesn't display the content of {{video.name}}, but a text: "{{video.name}}". I've read almost every post about this topic, but nothing helped me.

Comment: do you see any errors in console?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't. But when I remove dotdotdot expression from <p> it shows full title.

Comment: Use an angular filter instead of plugin

Comment: But does the filter work on the basis number of letter or the size of div? Because I need second option.

Answer (score 0):

You should call scope.$apply in your directive. This will cause your controller to update the model. See my example below

EDIT

Needed to add require: 'ngModel' so it would update everytime

EDIT 2

Turns out you should use the compile property of the directive and not link when using the directive within an ng-repeat

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myController', function($scope) {
  $scope.videos = [{
    name: 'Pool',
    thumbnail: 'http://img.youtube.com/vi/dXo0LextZTU/0.jpg'
  }, {
    name: 'Pool2',
    thumbnail: 'http://www.shender.com/db_picture/pro19/201105251714246730.jpg'
  }];
});

app.directive('dotdotdot', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    compile: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      return {
        pre: function(scope, element, attrs) {
          $(element).dotdotdot({
            'watch': true
          });
        }
      };
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jQuery.dotdotdot/1.7.4/jquery.dotdotdot.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <!-- Optional theme -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

  <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="myController">
  <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" ng-repeat="video in videos track by $index">
    <a href="{{thumbsPath + video.thumbnail}}" class="thumb">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img ng-src="{{thumbsPath + video.thumbnail}}" alt="">
        <div class="caption">
          <p class="video-title" dotdotdot>{{video.name}}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: After this change, it works, but only for first video. Next ones are still the same.

Comment: Good catch. I updated it so it would update evey time

Comment: I've updated it and now it displays only the first div with my thumbnail. :/
EDIT: Log from console: "Error: [$compile:ctreq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.16/$compile/ctreq?p0=ngModel&p1=dotdotdot
    at Error (native)"

Comment: Ok it turns out you need to use the compile instead of link in an ng-repeat. Hope this does it

Comment: The situation is getting stranger. When I reload the page all titles show up and after a moment some of them are changing to {{content}} and some of them stays. No logs in console.

Comment: hmm, sounds like another issue. I don't see that happening in my sample code. I even recreated it in this plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/csfjq9uZ2VelADLkurD8 and I don't see it changing to {{content}}

Comment: I've tried to use normal dotdotdot JQuery plugin (without using Angular), but unfortunately it also doesn't work at all.